# I need a hook that activates when a post or page is updated

Tags: wordpress, hook

I need a hook that activates when a post or page is updated

To control the cache of my web I need that when a content editor, publish, delete or modify any post or page activate this hook to be able to use code and control it.

I have post_row_actions but it does not work correctly

Answer (score 0):

you can use post_updated hook

look at

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated